# I have a kernal error that says,"ImportError: DLL load failed while importing win32api: The specified procedure could not be found"

Tags: pywin32, ansys

This kernel error is not letting me run any of my notebooks on jupyter notebooks. I was trying to run scripting code using pyansys and it just gave me the kernel error

I tried pip instal pywin32 but i get a message that says,"DEPRECATION: ansys-dpf-core 0.8.1 has a non-standard dependency specifier ansys-dpf-gate>=0.3.*. pip 23.3 will enforce this behaviour change. A possible replacement is to upgrade to a newer version of ansys-dpf-core or contact the author to suggest that they release a version with a conforming dependency specifiers. Discussion can be found at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/12063

I also tried pip install --upgrade pywin32==224 and I get a message that says :
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32==224 (from versions: 303, 304, 305, 306)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pywin32==224

Comment: Does it say which DLL?  If it is a Windows DLL you might need to upgrade your Windows OS to something more recent.  The app might be using Windows 10 API calls that your OS is too old to include.